# javascript image picker php

Tags: php, javascript, image, binding

im having dynamically created image tags, in php foreach function img scr=asdfsf.gif... so if i click on a particular image the src of the image store in a javascript variable

should not use onclick, use binding the image javascript..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **[live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)** method of jquery for that i suppose.